# Does Lipschitz continuous function only has a countable non-differentiable points?

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

If $f$ is Lipschitz, we know by Rademacher's theorem that it is differentiable a.e. That is, the set of non-differentiable points is of measure zero. But this does not necessarily imply that  it is a countable set.

Can we find a Lipschitz continuous function that has an uncountable differentiable points?

Comment: [This](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rae/1242738925) seems helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, from the paper below

> Differentiability of Lipschitz functions,
>   structure of null sets, and other problems. http://pagine.dm.unipi.it/alberti/ricerca/2010-12/acp-icm2010.pdf

we know that for a given set $E$, there exists a Lipschitz function such that $f$ is not differentiable at $E$ if and only if $E$ is of Lebesgue null.  It is easy to find a uncountable set of Lebesgue null, say Cantor set.