# Lipschitz continuous and strictly monotonic implies differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Is Lipschitz continuous and strictly monotonic will force function to be differentiable?

For Lipschitz continuous we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\le m|x-y|\,\,\forall \,x,y$ for some positive real $m$.

Comment: @Makar- The function $f(x)=x$ for $x\in (-1,0)$ and $f(x)=2x$ for $x\in (0,1)$ satisfies those conditions, but is not differentiable

Answer (score 2):

Take $ | x| + 2x $. It's monotonous and Lipschitz but not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: I was going through Rademacher Theorem which says that a Lipschitz function is differentiable almost everywhere. I got your answer but maybe with some extra condition like I tried mono tonic etc  can we say it is differentiable?

Comment: You can't do better than almost everywhere. Check this out:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444065/does-lipschitz-continuous-function-only-has-a-countable-non-differentiable-point