# Is a Lipschitz continuous function differentiable a.e. for at least one smooth path between every pair of points?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, lipschitz-functions

We know by Rademacher's theorem that a Lipschitz-continuous map is differentiable almost everywhere (a.e.).

Now for every path in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n>1$, there is a Lipschitz-continuous map such that it will be nowhere differentiable on that [path](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444065/does-lipschitz-continuous-function-only-has-a-countable-non-differentiable-point). But what about a given Lipschitz map. Can we find a path between every pair of points where it is a.e. differentiable?

Precisely, let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz map with $n>1$.  For every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, is it always possible to find a continuously differentiable path $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n$, with $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$, such than $f(\gamma(t))$ is differentiable a.e. on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Why isn't this true for *every* choice of continuously differentiable path $\gamma$? $f$ and $\gamma$ are Lipschitz, so $f \circ \gamma$ is Lipschitz, so $f \circ \gamma$ is differentiable a.e.

Comment: True. Then I guess the condition for a.e. differentiability of $f(\gamma(t))$ [here](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/papers/grad-thm-for-lipschitz.pdf) is superfluous? At least whenever $\gamma$ has a compact domain.